# Sending HTTP request using ruby on rails

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to ruby on rails and trying to test if I could do something like the below from my controller:

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET -d "{bbrequest:BBTest reqid:44  data:{name: "test"}}" http://localhost:8099
```

And what is the best practice to send JSON in your HTTP requests?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
def post_test
  require 'net/http'
  require 'json'

  @host = 'localhost'
  @port = '8099'

  @path = "/posts"

  @body ={
    "bbrequest" => "BBTest",
    "reqid" => "44",
    "data" => {"name" => "test"}
  }.to_json

  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(@path, initheader = {'Content-Type' =>'application/json'})
  request.body = @body
  response = Net::HTTP.new(@host, @port).start {|http| http.request(request) }
  puts "Response #{response.code} #{response.message}: #{response.body}"
end
```

Look up [Net::HTTP](http://www.rubyinside.com/nethttp-cheat-sheet-2940.html) for more information.

Comment: When I send HTTP request to the server using: curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET -d "{"bbrequest":"BBTest","reqid":"44","data":{"name":"test"}}" http://localhost:8099 ... my server sees JSON data as "{bbrequest:BBTest,reqid:44,data:{name:test}}"

When I send the request using the code you suggested, it sees it as "{\"bbrequest\":\"BBTest\",\"reqid\":\"44\",\"data\":{\"name\":\"
test\"}}" and server is unable to parse it, perhaps there are some extra options I need to set to send request from ruby to exclude those extra characters? Can you please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's because of converting the hash to json format. You will have to decode it. E.g. `{"a"=>"b"}.to_json` gives you `"{\"a\":\"b\"}"` and `ActiveSupport::JSON.decode("{\"a\":\"b\"}")` gives you `{"a"=>"b"}`.