# Send JSON data as post method from rails controller to a web service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to send some json data from my controller written in rails to a java webservice.

On form submission i take all the input fields data do some procession on it and convert it into json object using to_json.

But how can i send it to java webservice

```
http://localhost:8080/exim/jsonToMapService?jsonData={"key":"value"}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446888/sending-http-request-using-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 5):

You can use `net/http`. (as @Pierre wrote, you should create a class in lib folder, and put there your function)

```
url = URI.parse(service_url)
headers = {"host" => URL }
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.path)
req["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
req["Accept"] = "application/json"

req.body = JSON.generate(some_data)

con = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)

# ssl for https
if full_url.include?("https")
  con.use_ssl = true
  con.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
end

res = con.start {|http| http.request(req) }
```

Comment: Where did full_url come from?  Is it the same as service_url?

Answer (score 2):

To do things like this I suggest using either [RestClient](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) or [Faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday). Howeve I strongly suggest not doing the HTTP call in your controller.

Using RestClient, it would look like this:

```
RestClient.get('http://localhost:8080/exim/jsonToMapService', { key: :value })
```

You should create a class to extract this logic in the `lib` folder for example.

As @eightbitraptor mentioned it, when performing HTTP request like above, you should avoid blocking by performing them in a background process like [Delayed Job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job), [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) or [Sideqik](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq).

Comment: It's also worth thinking about whether you need to do this in request or out of band. If you make a HTTP request like this you'll end up blocking the users request until the request is complete. You might like to investigate a queueing/background jobs system like Delayed Job or Sidekick